# Apache NiFi 1.6.0 Error Post Upgrade

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

Just upgraded to the latest and grates NiFi 1.6.0 and i am getting a strange error on a ExecuteSQL Processor.

error: cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement

So the ExecuteSQL uses a Database Connection Pooling Service that runs some queries against a database in this case Vertica(with the latest jar), and there are multiple sequential queries.

I managed to fix the issue by rolling back my Apache NiFi Install to NiFi 1.5.0 and is all normal now.

I can also replicate the error.

I actually made a short Video on the behavior of the ExecuteSQL on 1.5.0 vs 1.6.0.

Demo of Error

Also Link: https://youtu.be/FJPf7PDmTSE

Any ideas ? maybe a bug with new release ?

Thx

As a Response to @Jagrut

- I wanna thank you for looking into it, but the issue is not the typo on my MariaDB SQL.

I have replicated the error once more

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvnwNz86EsY&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 4):

`NiFi 1.6` added support for parameterized statements in `ExecuteSQL` processor. This addressed [NIFI-978](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-978) via [PR 2433](https://github.com/apache/nifi/pull/2433).

`ExecuteSQL` processor takes a valid SQL select query, to be issued by the processor to the database. It does not indicate support for multiple select queries. ([NiFi v1.6](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL/index.html), [NiFi v1.5](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL/index.html))

In your [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJPf7PDmTSE), `MariaDB` connection is throwing the same exception for `v1.6` and `v1.5`, which is:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'select '2' as col1' at line 2
```

The error for `v1.6` appears at time `2:32` and the error for `v1.5` appears at time `4:25`.

[image: v1.6, MariaDB]

[image: v1.5, MariaDB]

Comment: Hi, that was a type there - can you look at the v.1.6 bottom error ? For MariaDb and Vertica. Same flow runs on 1.5 with no issues

Comment: MariaDB Connection is throwing error in both cases v1.5 and v.1.6

Comment: Hi @Jagrut you are correct ! This is because of the typo in the in my query, but also there is a JDBC Multiple Statement Error (focus on this one) Thx

Comment: Hi - I replicated your flow on NiFi 1.5 and 1.6, using MySQL DB. In both cases, ExecuteSQL succeeds if 1 query is specified `select '1' as col1;`. It fails if 2 queries are specified `select '1' as col1; select '2' as col1;`. The exception is `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version ...`. So, I don't think multiple select queries are supported in this processor, and the documentation also indicates the same.

Comment: As a Response to @Jagrut

- I wanna thank you for looking into it, but the issue is not the typo on my MariaDB SQL.
I have replicated the error once more 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvnwNz86EsY&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Hi - The error at 4:49 is from Vertica driver (`ERROR 2446: Cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement`). This is most likely due to NiFi 1.6 using `con.prepareStatement(selectQuery)`, vs NiFi 1.5 using `con.createStatement()`. Using `PreparedStatement` is better approach to execute a select query. Here, it seems that the Vertica driver does not support multiple statements via `con.prepareStatement(selectQuery)`, but it worked fine when using `con.statement()`. I think this is an issue with the Vertica driver. You can check if Vertica documents any config setting to allow this.

Comment: For reference - error code listed in Vertica docs: `https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ErrorCodes/SqlState-42601.htm`

Comment: Hi, thx for you reply - my question is not why the error is thrown ! is why in 1.5 is works and in 1.6 it does not ! and also is this something that we can track in NiFi release docs ? Thx

Comment: Hi - As I mentioned earlier, this processor is intended for a select query. The way your configuration with multiple queries was working in NiFi 1.5 was likely due to support from `Vertica` driver. NiFi 1.6 improved the processor to use `PreparedStatement`. But it seems Vertica driver does not support multiple queries via `PreparedStatement`, and hence throwing the error.  This is the link for release notes for 1.6, listing NIFI-978 (`https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12316020&version=12342422`).